# Does Google Calendar API allow resource calendars to be used for scalable non-Google users?

Tags: google-calendar-api

Do the Google Calendar terms of service and intent allow developers to use resource calendars to be used to build a scalable event service for non-Google users?

My question targets these concerns:

1. Is that a use case Google will allow in the long term?
2. Will Google approve requests to increase the necessary quotas to support hundreds of thousands of calendars tied to a single Google account?
3. Is there an SLA that is geared toward quick support resolution of calendar service issues, similar to Google Cloud Platform Support?

Comment: Apparently, your use-case is not very scalable. If you'll check the related [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26604244/5995040), having a single user handle all the request will make your app encounter this [error](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2905486?hl=en). This limitation is different from quota errors as stated on the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15537561/5995040) from that post.

Comment: What related post?

Comment: Did you nit see the links?