# Google Calendar Api v3 quota exceeded

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, google-calendar-api

I'm having a problem with creating calendar events ( With a google service account ), I have the Domain-wide Delegation enabled.

The error i'm getting is:
"Message[Calendar usage limits exceeded.] Location[ - ] Reason[quotaExceeded] Domain[usageLimits]"

I've checked the usage and its below 10 requests ( The quota is set to 1,000,000 )

This is my code:

```
string[] Scopes = { CalendarService.Scope.Calendar, CalendarService.Scope.CalendarEvents };

using (var stream = new FileStream("cred.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream)
                                 .CreateScoped(Scopes);
    var service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
    {
        HttpClientInitializer = credential,
        ApplicationName = "TEST",
    });

    var ev = new Event();
    EventDateTime start = new EventDateTime();
    start.DateTime = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30);

    EventDateTime end = new EventDateTime();
    end.DateTime = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(60);
    ev.Start = start;
    ev.End = end;
    ev.Summary = "Test";
    ev.Description = "Please Work";
    ev.Attendees = new List<EventAttendee>
    {
        new EventAttendee() { Email = "TestMail@gmail.com" }
    };

    var calendarId = "primary";
    service.Events.Insert(ev, calendarId).Execute();
```

If i try to execute the code without attendees it runs with out any error.

Did anyone encounter this problem before?

Comment: Maybe relate to this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15473732/google-calendar-api-calendar-usage-limits-exceeded

Comment: @lulucode I am in the poc phase, im sure i did not exceed the quota, and shared too many times the calendar, It happened on the first time i sent an api request

Answer (score 0):

**This is a known bug**

It has been reported on [Issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/141704931). You can click on the star next to the issue number to give more priority to the bug and to receive updates.

---

However, this has the current workaround (aside from not including attendees):

**Domain-Wide Delegation** or *impersonate a user*

You can read about how to do it [here](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation), the steps are:

1. Locate the newly-created service account in the table. Under
   Actions, click show more, then Edit.
2. In the service account details, click Show domain-wide delegation,
   then ensure the Enable G Suite Domain-wide Delegation checkbox is
   checked.
3. If you haven't yet configured your app's OAuth consent screen, you
   must do so before you can enable domain-wide delegation. Follow the
   on-screen instructions to configure the OAuth consent screen, then
   repeat the above steps and re-check the checkbox.
4. Click Save to update the service account, and return to the table of
   service accounts. A new column, Domain-wide delegation, can be seen.
   Click View Client ID, to obtain and make a note of the client ID.