# What is the limit for creating Calendar Events from a particular account per day, month and year?

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

I've tried to integrate google calendar API for Events creating. I would like to know if there is any limitations on the amount of Events that can be created for a day/month/year. If so how do I set to unlimited?

Comment: Have you done any research on your end already? Your question looks to be similar to the answers from https://stackoverflow.com/a/41887184/15384825 or https://github.com/manjeshpv/gsuite-google-calendar-api-limits. Based on these resources, there's also a limit when adding non-domain/external email accounts as guests to an event that is being created, aside from the official documentation about limits on creating events at https://support.google.com/a/answer/2905486. Additionally, please see https://cloud.google.com/docs/quota#requesting_higher_quota (Requesting a higher quota limit).

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you should know. First being that the Google Calendar api is under the same limitations as the Google Calendar website.  There for all the limits that would apply to a user creating events in Google calendar will apply to a user using your Application creating events

[Avoid Calendar use limits](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2905486?hl=en)

[image]

The second think you need to under stand is quota limits for your project in [Google Cloud console](https://console.cloud.google.com/)

There are two types of quotas project based and user based.  Project based quotas limit your full project can make a cross all its users.

Then there is user based quotas which is the limit to the number of requests a single user can make in your project.

[image]

If you have a 10k request per minute quota for your project and each user has a 600 request per minute quota.

You can apply to extend the project based quota but not the user based quota.

Comment: Thanks but I really need to increase the quota limit and would like to know how it can be done for unlimited no of events and calendars because we are working on creating a application for schools and trying to create a meetup link for every class period and with our volume of users and application usage across the globe, I don't think 100,000 events and 60 calendar won't work for our application. If you could guide us on the right track, I would be pleased. We need to have unlimited create Events/Calendars and paid option also would work for us

Comment: The only quotas you can change are the project based ones in google cloud console you can click the edit quotas button and apply for a quota extension.  See the image the button say edit quotas.  Google is not going to give you an unlimited quota you need to be reasonable.   You will not be able to get the Google calendar based quotas changed.